# r.js optimizer just copies javascript files to build directory

Tags: javascript, requirejs, minify, r.js

I am trying to use r.js to minify and uglify the entire project. But when i run the command 
r.js -o app.build.js 
It just optimizes the CSS file and copies all javascript files to build directory. Javascript files are not minified or uglified. here is my app.build.js file

```
({
appDir: "../",
baseUrl: "js",
dir: "../../release",
paths: {
    "dojo": "empty: ",
    "esri": "empty: ",
    "text": "empty:"
},
optimize: "uglify",
removeCombined: true,
inlineText: true,
modules: [{
    name: "app"
}],
optimizeCss: "standard",
})
```

Project structure

```
MyApp
 src
   js
     assets
     core_library
     helpers
     libs
     nls
     theme
     widgets
     app.build.js
     app.js
     main.js
  index.html
```

I am looking for some directions to resolve this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you give us a bit of an idea of how your file directory looks like? Under modules you have 'app' - does this mean you have a ../js/app.js file?

Comment: @Felix Yes you are correct. I have a /js/app.js. I have also updated my post to include project structure

Comment: I resolve this issue myself. Interestingly r.js does not throw any error in windows environment. I used Ubantu to build the application and received an error unable to find dijit directory inside my application. I added following line under paths object and bingo build was successful : "dijit":"empty:"